# Trying to read information from a text file in C

Tags: c, file, input, io

I'm trying to read the following text file:

Parameters.txt:

```
Memory Size: 8000 
Number Cores: 1
Quantum: 100
Schedule Algorithm: FCFS
Memory Allocation: First
Swap Time: OFF
Thread Quantum: OFF
```

and save each value as a variable (8000, 1, 100, "FCFS", "First", "OFF", "OFF"). I started off by just reading the value of memSize (8000).

I have the following C code:

```
FILE *parameters;
parameters=(fopen("./Parameters.txt","r"));
if(parameters==NULL){
    printf("Error reading file.");
    exit(1);
}
char * strTemp;
int memSize, numCores, quantum, swapTime;
char * schedAlg, memAlloc;
fscanf(parameters, "%s %s %d", strTemp, strTemp, memSize);
```

However, I get a segmentation fault from this.  I've debugged the code to narrow down the seg fault to the fscanf() line.

Am I overcomplicating things when trying to read this file?

Comment: Hint: What does `strTemp` point to?

Comment: You've not allocated any memory to `strTemp`. Where do you expect the words *Memory* and *Size:* to be read into?

Comment: Oh dear. If you are attempting to write an OS, I suggest you give up now:(

Comment: Thanks; I'm super rusty on C.  Yes, strTemp is a pointer, so I'd need to add &strTemp to my fscanf call.  And yes, I'm attempting to write an OS; not giving up yet, though!

Comment: @MartinJames There's a huge difference between writing an OS, and writing a *good* OS. Writing an OS is doable by most C programmers, with a bit of Google-able arcane knowledge. (Even if all it ends up being is a basic command prompt with no useful commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FILE *parameters;
parameters=(fopen("./Parameters.txt","r"));
if(parameters==NULL){
    printf("Error reading file.");
    exit(1);
}
char *strTemp = malloc(80);
int memSize, numCores, quantum, swapTime;
char *schedule = malloc(80), memAlloc = malloc(80);
fscanf(parameters, "%s %s %d", strTemp, strTemp, &memorize);
```

In your code, `strTemp`, `schedule` and `memAlloc` are nothing more than a pointer to char. However, to hold a string, you need a block of memory, so you have to allocate some memory for the pointers.

BTW, If I were you, I would write `fscanf(parameters, " %*[^:] :%d", &memorize);` to avoid the unnecessary use of `strTemp`.